# If you delete your save data in a Pokémon game, do Pokémon you've traded to other games get deleted in those games?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Can you reset Pokémon and keep all your Pokémon you may have moved into another game? For instance, if you put all your Pokémon from ORAS into XY, can it still delete all of your Pokémon even if they're in another game?

What would happen to my Pokémon in other games if I reset ORAS?

Comment: Trading was intended as something between friends, having them lose their Mons because you deleted your game would make trading redundant.

Comment: @user124034 Plus it would really troublesome to keep track of what game is still running and what has been reset. How would a game make the difference between a reset game and a game that has not been switched on for a long time? A pokemon is basically like a file and is not linked to the computer that created it except for the computer name which has little to no significance in the way the file operates. On another hand, there's no reason to keep the master ball. If you used it, so be it and move on. You can catch any Pokemon without it.

Answer (score 12):

**No. You would not lose your Pokémon if you transfered them to another game.**

Since the other game (in your case, X/Y) has no idea that the OR/AS game has been reset, it cannot destroy the pokémon.

Even if it could somehow contact the other game and delete the pokémon, this would provide grief for those on the receiving end of trades as they would lose pokémon (because some random person they traded with reset their game). Hence this feature is left out intentionally.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot delete Pokémon in another game, even if you reset yours. You can also use the Pokémon Bank, instead of another game.

Furthermore, you can catch all Pokémon with other balls then the Masterball. Put it to sleep/paralyze, bring it to 1HP (with [False Swipe](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/False_Swipe_(move))), throw dusk balls (in night or cave). No need to absolutely have that Masterball.

Comment: I confirm copying pokemon to pokebank then reseting the game won't erase transfered pokemon from pokebank.